# Add character after length Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to add the character "e" after 12 characters. something like this:

```
theworldwillndsoon
```

should be this:

```
theworldwillendsoon
```

how can I do it in notepad++?

Comment: Regex replace with a [a-z]{12} ?

Comment: if that string needs to be changed a bunch of times, find and replace.

Comment: Include your attempt in your post please.

Comment: Click the mouse between the `l` and `n`, and then type `e`. What? That's not what you mean? Ok. Click at the start of the line, then use the right arrow 12 times, and then type the `e`. No? That's not it either? Perhans you should explain in more detail what you're asking for help in doing, then - your question is entirely too vague.

Comment: Hold `ALT` and set a 'super height cursor' at column 12 by dragging the mouse with LMB down over all lines to edit. Then press `e` once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you would click `Search` -> `Replace`, check the Regular expression checkbox under Search Mode.

```
Find: ^(.{12})
Replace: \1e
```

**Note**: The dot `.` matches any single character (except newline), `\1` is reference to the capture group `()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this, which will insert whatever after 12 whatever?

Find what:

```
(?<=^.{12})
```

Replace with:

```
e
```

Using a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

In replace-tab > search mode:
Option for Regular expression has to be checked.

Comment: You should probably mention that this works in the latest versions of Notepad++ only, because lookbehinds don't work on previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I only tried it with my version 6.5.2 and there it worked :-)